# Sequelize: difference of DataTypes and Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have seen the use of both classes for defining data types, including in the official documentation, both apparently serve the same purpose.

On a tutorial, I saw the application was using DataTypes for the Model and Sequelize for Migrations, you can exchange between them and they continue to work. Example codes:

Model using DataTypes:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Driver = sequelize.define('Driver', {
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
```

Migration using Sequelize:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Drivers', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
```

Comment: I wanna know if we need to write types exactly same in models and migration files, writing `DataTypes.INTEGER(50)` works fine in model, but throws syntax error when written in migration file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second parameter in both of them is just the sequelize package itself

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
```

You'll notice in your index.js of models (if you set up as suggested) that you do something like the below, where you are passing in sequelize as the second argument.

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

This exposes the data types. It doesn't matter what you call it. For example

```
  module.exports = (sequelize, asd) => {
    const Driver = sequelize.define('Driver', {
    firstName: {
      type: asd.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
```

Same with migrations.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes), DataTypes is:

> A convenience class holding commonly used data types.